# How do we upgrade openssl mobule in apache2 serivce on windows (XAMPP)

Tags: openssl

Download the latest version of Apache on Apache VS17 binaries and modules download 4
Save zipped file locally, unzip the file
Go to the server, stop and uninstall apache service through XAMPP control panel
On the downloaded apache folder, copy the libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll, libssl-1_1-x64.dll, and openssl.exe. These can be found in the bin folder
Replace files in $location\xampp\apache\bin with the above files
Install and start apache service through XAMPP control panel
Check if you have the latest version, it can be done by opening XAMPP control panel → Shell, type command ‘openssl’ enter, ‘version’ enter.

the openssl is upgrade to latest version.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.